# how to sort a multidimensional array according to current time?

Tags: php, arrays

> I have an array like

```
$arr = array(

        array(
            'id'=>'1',
            'time'=>'08:00'
            ),
        array(
            'id'=>'2',
            'time'=>'11:00'
            ),
        array(
            'id'=>'3',
            'time'=>'14:00'
            ),
        array(
            'id'=>'4',
            'time'=>'17:00'
            )
       );
```

what i want is suppose if the time is 11:30 i want the third array(time->14:00) to come in the first position of the array and the rest to come underneath it. I'm using PHP 5.3 (That's all far i can go with the technology).

> The output should be:

```
array(
      array(
            'id'=>'1',
            'time'=>'14:00'
            ),
       array(
            'id'=>'2',
            'time'=>'17:00'
            )
        array(
            'id'=>'3',
            'time'=>'08:00'
            ),
        array(
            'id'=>'4',
            'time'=>'11:00'
            )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `usort` for that:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
   $aTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d ' . $a['time']));
   $bTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d ' . $b['time']));
   $time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 13:00'));

   if ($aTime > $time && $bTime < $time)
       return -1; // $a is in future, while $b is in past
   elseif ($aTime < $time && $bTime > $time)
       return 1; // $a is in past, while $b is in future
   else
       return $aTime - $bTime; // $a and $b is either in future or in past, sort it normally.
});
```

[Live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5eeb308f740cdc535fe17e5b8950538ee925f6d)

Comment: @rahul no, all sorting functions changes original array

Answer (score 3):

You could use this callback to `usort`:

```
$t = date("h:m") . "_"; // add a character so it cannot be EQUAL to any time in the input
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($t) {
    return strcmp($a["time"],$b["time"]) * strcmp($t,$a["time"]) * strcmp($t,$b["time"]);
});
```

#### Explanation

First the current time is retrieved in HH:MM format. A character is appended to it so to make sure none of the time strings in the input array will exactly match it. This will ensure that calling `strcmp` with the current time as argument, and an input date as other argument, will never return 0, but either -1 or 1. Note that -1 means that the first argument is less than the second argument. 1 means the opposite.

The callback passed to `usort` will be called for several pairs of input time strings and should return a negative or positive value (or 0) to indicate how the pair should be ordered in the output: negative means the first value should come before the second, 0 means they are identical and can be ordered any way, and 1 means the second should be ordered before the first.

The return value is here a multiplication of three values, each the result of `strcmp`. The second and third can never be zero.

When the second and third value are equal (both 1 or both -1), it means that the two input times are at the same side of the current time: either both before the current time, or both after it. The product of these two factors is then 1.

When these values are not equal (one is 1, the other -1), then it means the two input times are at different sides of the current time, and so their order should be opposite. The product is then -1.

Finally, the first factor tells us how the two input values compare to eachother. This should be reversed when the above mentioned product is -1, and indeed the multiplication will take care of that.

Comment: @trincot you could described how it works by comments in the answer itself. No doubt that your solution is correct.

Comment: @commonsense, I added an explanation.

Comment: @Rahul, I added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
  $t = time();
  $a = $t < ($a = strtotime($a['time'])) ? $a : $a + 86400; // +1 day
  $b = $t < ($b = strtotime($b['time'])) ? $b : $b + 86400;
  return $a <=> $b;
});
```